# how to call function on any route inside react router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am building a react/redux/thunk application. I have some routes working and rendering components. Currently I have a `Routes` file with all my routes that I render inside my ReactDOM.

it is a shop application that I want to sync with my server so that when ever the app loads, it loads the application with the correct stuff from the database. so if someone has products in their basket I want them to be in the basket when the app loads

I'm struggling of thinking of a way to do this. I was thinking of calling it in `componentDidMount` but that only gets called for the particular component, so if the user was to hit a different route then it wouldn't be called and there basket wouldn't be synced. so is there a way to call a function on every route change? or a different solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If the cart info is something that is used on every page/route you should probably have a component that gets loaded/included on every route - like a header - in which you could do the call to fetch the cart data (If not already loaded).

```
<Switch>
  <Route path='...' component={Comp1} /> // <-- wont load cart info
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentThatFetchesCartInfo/> // <-- this will get included in every route inside Fragment
    <Route path='...' component={comp2}/>
    <Route path='...' component={comp3}/>
  </Fragment>
</Switch>
```

Comment: hmm, I have that but for some reason it wont call `componentDidMount` on every route change?

Comment: Are the consuming components connected to redux? and using that data?
In the above example you still need to connect comp2 and comp3 to redux.

Comment: they are connected to redux yes but that should not matter as `componentDidMount` is react

Comment: Ok - So the header will load once on first load and then the data should be available on every route. componentDidMount will not be called on route change as the 'header' is already loaded and data available.

Comment: thanks for the help but found this which seems good: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/3554

Comment: You're welcome.The drawback with that approach is that you will be pulling the cart info on every route change which may not be needed(As it may already be loaded in your global state).Not a concern but not the ideal approach imho.